# How do I make my image cover the status bar (ignore the safety area)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make the image ignore safety areas I've tried looking on the internet and tried playing around with the code but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone please help me?

If you don't understand what I mean. this Is what my app looks like
[this I what my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVd2n.jpg)

and this is what I would like it to look like.[this is what I would like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZdY1.png)

and here's my code:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Image("Home-Slider1_Hitachi")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) behind your ScrollView.

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Image("Home-Slider1_Hitachi")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) 
    }
}
```

If your ***Home*** view is nested into another view, the view itself (where you call it) will need that modification.

Btw. it is just ignoring the top one, you can also do .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.**all**) to ignore all.

Best, Sebastian

Comment: Thanks, I was putting it on the stack and not the scroll view